# Vue: Can watchers be used to watch a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to see if I can use a watcher method to look for a change in a computed property rather than watching the individual store properties here.  Would that work or can they only be used on data properties and props?

```
computed: {
      optionsTrue() {
            return this.$store.getters.getOption1IsTrue && this.$store.getters.getOption2IsTrue
      } 
},
watch: {
     optionsTrue(newVal) {
         // would this work to check when the value of the computed property has changed or can watcher only watch data properties?
     }
```

}

Comment: Yes, it would work. Just try it.

Comment: Yes watchers can be used to watch computed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
computed: {
  completed: function () {
     return this.required && this.textAnswer !== '';
  },
},
watch: {
  completed: function(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).